# Handling JSON Objects in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, cyclejs

I am new to cyclejs and rxjs in general and was hoping someone could help me solve my problem.
I am trying to build a demo application for my understanding and stuck with rendering JSON objects on the DOM.

- My demo application calls the NASA near earth objects API for the past 7 days and tries to display them.
- There is a `Load More` button at the bottom which on clicking will load  data of the previous 7 days (`Today - 7` upto `Today - 14`).
- The response I get from the API is as follows

  `{
  "links" : {
      "next" : "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2016-09-06&end_date=2016-09-12&detailed=false&api_key=DEMO_KEY",
      "prev" : "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2016-08-25&end_date=2016-08-31&detailed=false&api_key=DEMO_KEY",
      "self" : "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2016-08-31&end_date=2016-09-06&detailed=false&api_key=DEMO_KEY"
    },
    "element_count" : 39,
    "near_earth_objects" : {
      "2016-09-06" : [{
        some data
      },
      {
        some data
      }],
      2016-08-31: [{...}],
      ...
      }
  }`

I am interested in near_earth_objects JSON object but I am unable to map it beacause of it being an Object.
How do I handle such a situations? Below is the code that I have

```
function main(sources) {
    const api_key = "DEMO_KEY";
    const clickEvent$ = sources.DOM.select('.load-more').events('click');
    const request$ = clickEvent$.map(() => {
        return {
            url: "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-06&end_date=2016-09-13&api_key=" + api_key,
            method: "GET"
        }
    }).startWith({
        url: "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2016-08-31&end_date=2016-09-06&api_key=" + api_key,
        method: "GET"
    });
    const response$$ = sources.HTTP.filter(x$ => x$.url.indexOf("https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed") != -1).select(response$$);
    const response$ = response$$.switch(); //flatten the stream
    const nasa$ = response$.map(response => {
        return response.body
    });

    const sinks = {
        DOM: nasa$.map(nasa =>
            ([nasa.near_earth_objects]).map(objects => {
                var vdom = [];
                //I am not very happy with this part. Can this be improved?
                for (var key in objects) {
                    if (objects.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        vdom.push(objects[key].map(obj => div([
                            h1(obj.name)
                        ])))
                    }
                }
                //returning the vdom does not render on the browser. vdom is an array of arrays. How should i correct this?
                console.log(vdom);
                return vdom;
            })
        ),
        HTTP: request$
    };
    return sinks;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, you want to extract the entries of `nasa.near_earth_objects` (i.e., turn the Object into an Array), then flat map that Array into an Observable sequence.

> I'll assume you're already using [lodash](https://lodash.com) in your project (you can do it without lodash, but you'll just need to write more glue code manually). I'll also assume you're importing RxJS' Observable as `Rx.Observable`; adjust the names below to suite your code.

You can accomplish the first task using `_.toPairs(nasa.near_earth_objects)`, and the second part by calling `.flatMap()`, and returning `Rx.Observable.from(near_objects)`. The resulting Observable will emit items for each key in `nasa.near_earth_objects`. Each item will be an array, with `item[0]` being the item's key (e.g., `2016-09-06`) and `item[1]` being the item's value.

Using that idea, you can replace your `DOM` sink with something like:

```
nasa$.map(nasa => _.toPairs(nasa.near_earth_objects))
    .flatMap(near_objects => Rx.Observable.from(near_objects))
    .map(near_object => div([
        h1(near_object[1].name)
    ]))
),
```

Comment: I did exactly the same thing but without flatMap, only difference, figured it out on my own after struggling quite a bit. Helped me get my concepts straight. Thanks a lot.